# jquery running after all javascript has ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

I've been trying to make an RSS reader with JQuery and javascript, but it turns out that javascript doesn't wait for jquery to end before continuing, causing the some registrations to fail.

The console.logs of the example show that the logs of the jquery function are showing up after the logs of the common javascript. This causes the result of the function to change, because it depends on the jquery function.
I'd like to know how to make javascript wait for jquery to end before continuing. The idea is that all of the process marked with ** occur before the "after the calling" log

Here are the logs and the code. Thank you for your help

----Before the calling

**Calling a check_feed

**was there activity: false

----After the calling

----variable result: noact

**judging item0

**hora vs ult_act: 1480805684 > 1480798209 = true

**New message from coyoteazul

**judging item1

**hora vs ult_act: 1480766258 > 1480798209 = false

**judging item2

**hora vs ult_act: 1480743686 > 1480798209 = false

** SHOWS A NOTIFICATION

```
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
function caller(){
  console.log("----Before the calling")
  var result = check_Feed("https://www.neobux.com/rss/?/601750/", 1480798309)
  console.log("----After the calling")
  console.log("----variable result: " + result)
}


function check_Feed (FEED_URL, ult_act){
  ult_act = parseInt(ult_act)
  console.log("**Calling a check_feed")
  var titul;
  var contador = 0;
  var actividad = false;

  $.get(FEED_URL, function (data) {
    titul = $(data).find("title").first().text();
    if (titul == "") {return "F"} //el titulo solo puede estar vacio si el feed esta cerrado

    $(data).find("item").each(function () {
      console.log("**judging item" + contador)
      if (contador < 7){
        var el = $(this);
        var hora = el.find("pubDate").text()
            hora = new Date(hora).getTime()/1000;

        console.log("**hora vs ult_act: " + hora + " > " + (ult_act-100) + " = " + (hora > (ult_act-100)))

        if (hora > (ult_act-100)){ //solo notifica si la hora supera a la ultima activdad.
          var cuerpol = el.children().last().text();
              cuerpol = "New message from " + cuerpol;
          var linkl = el.find("link").text();
          console.log("**"+cuerpol)

          setTimeout(function(){ //en firefox si no se muestran a traves de un timeout solo mostrara la 1er notificacion
            console.log("** SHOWS A NOTIFICATION");}, 500 * (contador+1))
            actividad = true;
        }
        contador ++;
      }
    });
  });
  console.log("**was there activity: " + actividad);
  if (actividad)
    return "act";
  else
    return "noact";
}


caller()
```

Comment: Do you mean you have issues with callback?

Comment: Not exactly. The callback works ok, it happens after jquery "gets". The problem is that the rest of javascript keeps running before the callback is executed

Comment: This is expected. Your code is working as expected. [jQuery get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) calls are asynchronous by default unless you specify to be synchronous explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things before you try out the code below:

- jQuery get/post are simple ajax calls that run asynchronously. To
  understand them you may start
  [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/)
- [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) also works out in a similar fashion , in essence it executes a function once the time specified elapses.

Try running this code to see the results in the order you are expecting

```
function caller() {
  console.log("----Before the calling")
  check_Feed("https://www.neobux.com/rss/?/601750/", 1480798309);
  thisGetsPrintedRightAfter();
}

thisGetsCalledAfterEverything = function(result) {
  console.log("----After the calling")
  console.log("----variable result: " + result)
}

thisGetsPrintedRightAfter = function() {
  console.log("This gets printed right after Calling a check_feed");
}

function check_Feed(FEED_URL, ult_act) {
  ult_act = parseInt(ult_act)
  console.log("**Calling a check_feed")
  var titul;
  var contador = 0;
  var actividad = false;

  $.get(FEED_URL, function(data) {
    titul = $(data).find("title").first().text();
    if (titul == "") {
      return "F"
    } //el titulo solo puede estar vacio si el feed esta cerrado

    $(data).find("item").each(function() {
      console.log("**judging item" + contador)
      if (contador < 7) {
        var el = $(this);
        var hora = el.find("pubDate").text()
        hora = new Date(hora).getTime() / 1000;

        console.log("**hora vs ult_act: " + hora + " > " + (ult_act - 100) + " = " + (hora > (ult_act - 100)))

        if (hora > (ult_act - 100)) { //solo notifica si la hora supera a la ultima activdad.
          var cuerpol = el.children().last().text();
          cuerpol = "New message from " + cuerpol;
          var linkl = el.find("link").text();
          console.log("**" + cuerpol);
          setTimeout(function() { //en firefox si no se muestran a traves de un timeout solo mostrara la 1er notificacion
            console.log("** SHOWS A NOTIFICATION");
            console.log("**was there activity: " + actividad);
            if (actividad)
              thisGetsCalledAfterEverything("act");
            else
              thisGetsCalledAfterEverything("noact");;
          }, 500 * (contador + 1));
          actividad = true;
        }
        contador++;
      }
    });
  });
}


caller()
```

Comment: Thanks! I had read about ajax but i thought it was something different of jquery (i just started learning about jquery about 2 days ago).

Comment: JQuery is just a library built on top of JavaScript. It makes traditional JavaScript easier to use. Glad I could help you, all the best!